# Unable to clear the contents of Datavalidation in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA function that will bind an array to excel range and in turn use that range to specify a data validation list for the selected range.

Below is the function that will create the datavalidation list.

```
Private Function CreateDataValidation(ByVal pobjRange As Range, ByVal pvarArrayEntries As Variant) As Boolean

Const PICKLIST_COLUMN = "IV"

CreateDataValidation = True


If UBound(pvarArrayEntries) = 0 Then
    pobjRange.Validation.Delete
Else
    '
    ' Select Range
    '
    Dim lobjPicklistRange As Range
    Set lobjPicklistRange = Application.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, PICKLIST_COLUMN), Cells(UBound(pvarArrayEntries) + 1, PICKLIST_COLUMN))
    '
    ' Clear existing Column
    '
    lobjPicklistRange.Clear
    '
    ' Write entries to the picklist column
    '
    lobjPicklistRange = pvarArrayEntries

    Dim lstrFormula As String
    lstrFormula = "=" & PICKLIST_COLUMN & "1:" & PICKLIST_COLUMN & UBound(pvarArrayEntries) + 1

    If Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1 Then
        lstrFormula = Application.ConvertFormula(lstrFormula, xlA1, xlR1C1)
    End If

    With pobjRange.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=lstrFormula
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End If
```

End Function

Issue is that, when i bind the range with the array values the drop down appears, when i select the same range and pass an empty array to the above method the drop down doesn't disappear. 
Which means that the code in the function

```
If UBound(pvarArrayEntries) = 0 Then
    pobjRange.Validation.Delete
```

doesn't work. Any help in clearing a range with which already contains a datavalidation drop down would be of great help. i tried Range.clearcontents and validation.delete nothing worked.

For your information,the above function is called on Workbook_SheetSelectionChange event

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you passing the empty array?

Comment: @Rory Hi, By using the below  `code`  ReDim pvarArrayEntries(0, 1)

If CreateDataValidation(pobjRange, pvarArrayEntries) = True Then
    'blah blah
End If

Comment: Given that you delete any existing validation either way, why don't you put that bit **before** the `Ubound` test and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Array (0,1) contains two elements, no?

Comment: @Rory i tried that it didn't work. The drop down still shows the values that it is bound to.

Comment: @Daniel yes the array contains two elements that have empty values. I'm ok if it can show empty values as the drop down but it shows the old values.

Answer (score 0):

I could find a workaround for this problem, by setting InCellDropdown to false, this way if the array has no elements, by setting the above property to false the drop down will not be visible and user will not be able to set any value. 
Thanks all for you inputs.